# MLAPP Matlab in C# wont open in other computer

Tags: c#, matlab

i have this code for my c# program :

```
MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp(); 
matlab.Execute("cd d:\");
matlab.Execute("run textcreator.m");
```

this is run on my computer with matlab r2013b 64-bit, but command window textcreator.m wont run in other computer with matlab r2016a 64 bit. it give this error :

```
retrieving the com class factory for component with clsid
```

why this is happend?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific than "won't run". Do you have some error? Is it a run-time problem or a compilation-time problem? Is the system setup exactly the same way with the exception of the MATLAB version?

Comment: Usually if it is work, matlab command window will show up. It is just not showing anything.

Comment: Try adding `matlab.Visible = 1` after you instantiate MLApp. If this does not work, it is likely that the other PC does not have the COM object properly registered, try starting MATLAB r2016a and running command `matlab /regserver` from the command window.

Comment: so, actually it give this error : retrieving the com class factory for component with clsid. i run r2013b 64-bit and check in other computer r2016a 64 bit.